# Save lock-files to a directory instead of disabling them

Tags: lock-files

Emacs 24 introduced the ability to disable the creation of the infamous `.#file-name` lock  files.

Evaluating the following lisp form will completely disable Emacs ability to lock files to prevent concurrent changes.

**Is there a way to set Emacs to save lock files in a dedicated directory**, similarly to what happens with auto-save and backup files?

```
(setq create-lockfiles nil)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not straightforward to do considering `F1 v create-lockfiles` takes you to `filelock.c` which only exposes this variable and `temporary-file-directory`. So, to have this behaviour you'd either need to replace nearly all functions exposed in that file with your own Emacs Lisp functions or hand in a bug via `M-x report-emacs-bug` and hope for the best.

Comment: I submitted a bug report at https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=31908.

Comment: Definitely helps. Webpack keeps failing because of these lock files.

Comment: Submit a bug report for webpack?  (Why would it think these were files of interest?)

Answer (score 5):

Emacs-28 can now put lock-files in different locations, see [`lock-file-name-transforms`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Locks.html#index-lock_002dfile_002dname_002dtransforms)