# What are .#foo files?

Tags: lock-files

I have placed my autosave and backup files in a single directory `.emacs-saves`.

Backup files appear as `~foo`

Autosave files appear as `#foo#`

But Emacs seems to also generate `.#foo` in the current directory whenever a change is made in a buffer.

What's the purpose of these files and is there a way to specify their default directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are lock files. See [Save lock-files to a directory instead of disabling them](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5967/save-lock-files-to-a-directory-instead-of-disabling-them)

If you are accessing files remotely (think `tramp` or `nfs`) then it is a lot simpler to have the lock files in the same directory as the file being edited.

Comment: Thanks, what is the purpose of the lock files? Is it just to prevent other applications opening these files while they are being edited or are there other reasons for these files?

Comment: Actually, nevermind, found the answer here https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Interlocking.html