# Still getting autosave files in the same directory as my buffer

Tags: auto-save, backup

I have the following in my init file:

```
(setq backup-directory-alist
      `((".*" . ,temporary-file-directory)))
(setq auto-save-file-name-transforms
      `((".*" ,temporary-file-directory t)))
```

Despite this, I still occasionally get backup files placed in the same directory as my buffer with the following name format: `".#filename"`. It has gotten annoying enough that I have considered disabling the backup files altogether, but I'd prefer not to. Is there a way that I can tell Emacs to save ***all*** backup files in the temporary directory?

I am on Emacs 28.1.

Comment: These are not backup files: they are lock files. See e.g. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29761/what-are-foo-files

Comment: See also [File Locks](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Locks.html)

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful.